# 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded while unit testing with database transactions

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am doing some unit testing using phpunit. When I run the tests it hangs fora while, then I get an error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1205 Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction 
>   (SQL: update `booking_product` set `klarna_invoiceId` = 7777, `klarna_product_status` = 3, `updated_at` = 2016-03-30 18:43:43 where `booking_id` = 8 and `product_id` = 1)

If I don't use database transactions I don't have this problem. Some of the tests are working on the same database record.

I'm sure I'm doing sometihng wrong, how do I resolve this issue?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you have implemented the `tearDown()` method, you have to call the parent's `tearDown()`:

```php
public function tearDown()
{
    parent::tearDown();

    // ... your code ...
}
```